# stoping and starting IIS 6.0 or my application pool on IIS using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have two windows boxes. one is windows xp(local computer) where i need to write a batch file and the other is windows server 2003 where my IIS is located. Now i need to write a batch file in windows Xp that needs to do these below mentioned operations in it.

1. Stop the IIS or my application pool on that IIS.
2. Start the IIS or my application pool on that IIS.

   These stop and start need to be performed in two different lines. The windows Server 2003 box has a different user id and password to my windows xp(local computer). As i am new to writing the batch files, after my one day of struggle i am just able to kill the process of my application pool(w3wp.exe) on IIS which is located in the windows server 2003 and i am still not sure what i have written is correct or not. Please help me how to stop and start the IIS which is on server 2003 box, as the batch file should be on the xp box. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally after a long struggle i made it work by "starting and stopping the iis from remote box with different id and password". I have initially tried runas command which didn't work and then i moved on to ps tools and used this below mentioned commands.

psexec \COMPUTER_NAME -u USERID -p PASSWORD iisreset.exe /START ----> for starting the iis
psexec \COMPUTER_NAME -u USERID -p PASSWORD iisreset.exe /STOP  ----> for stoping the iis

@djhayman --- Thanks for your help man.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in program for starting/stopping/restarting IIS - iisreset.exe

Calling this program on its own will stop and then restart IIS. If you want to just stop IIS without starting it again, use the following:

> iisreset.exe /STOP

And then later you can start it again like this:

> iisreset.exe /START

This should work for all versions of IIS, regardless of the operating system version. Just remember that you need to execute it as an administrator.

**EDIT:** Just noticed that you want to run the command from your XP box to restart IIS on a W2K3 box - there is an optional parameter to specify the target computer:

> iisreset.exe ServerNameOrIp /STOP

And:

> iisreset.exe ServerNameOrIp /START

Comment: do i need to specify the id and password for that box. because my local box which is xp has a different login id and password compared to the server 2003 box where IIS is located.

Comment: Did you see my edit at the bottom? You can provide the server's network name or IP address as an optional argument, which will let you remotely (i.e. from a different computer) start/stop IIS.

Comment: sorry i just posted my comment and you edited it at the same time i have edited my previous comment asking about the id and password, can you please take a look at it..

Comment: You need to have an administrator account on the server with the exact same username/password as the user you are running on the XP box, and it should be able to remotely iisreset without sending any usernames/passwords.

Comment: i think having the same user name password is not possible. is there any way that i can do this by sending the user name and password?